# How to update Touchpad drivers in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: touchpad

Have noticed right click and left click wont work in touchpad  but i can use the toucpad to move the cursor around but wont click anything, Wireless mouse works fine though, So i thought it has an outdated touchpad driver

Comment: Are you using wayland or xorg?  Please append your question with the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: Iam using Xorg.